# VB.NET DataGridView not Returning Complete Value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to read the value of a cell that I have just typed into, using the CellValueChanged event of a DataGridView and the following line

```
Dim InitialString As String = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString
```

The value in the cell is "11048109 20OCT2015 J5572 51" but InitialString has a value of "11048109" and the rest of the string is missing.

I have also used this line...

```
InitialString = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString
```

With the same result. Am I using the wrong event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you remove the space after 11048109 does it still return the same value? What are you using to populate your gridview? (an sql table)

Comment: The source of the data is actually a hand held scanner, so essentially the data will be 'typed' into each cell, yes the space is stopping us from getting the entire string, removing the space captures more of the string, but I don't understand why

Comment: Is the data type being converted a datetime object? If so try Dim initialDate as DateTime = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex).Value If the value is no longer being cut off then your problem was the conversion of the value from datetime to string.  Keep in mind if the data type is anything else but string, it can be a conversion issue.  Find out the datatype of the cell you're trying to retrieve

Comment: another suggestion might be to post all of your front end and back-end code for datagridview1, that way someone else can run the code to see if they are getting the same thing.